# Airflow Out of a Container when a Liquid is pumped in

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, flow

I'm working on a project at work.  We pump different media into a 45L bottle through a 3/16" tube.  The has a 3/16" vent line that is 13" long with a 0.2um filter.  The project is to reduce the length of the vent line to 2".

I've been challenged on it with the question "Does reducing the vent line length increase the pressure in the bottle when pumping into it?"  Is the shorter length somehow reducing the flow rate of air out of the bottle or create back pressure?

It's been a long time since I've taken physics but my thoughts on this are that there is no change.  The pump produces a flow rate of ~300 ml/s.  This should displace ~300ml of air per sec in the bottle out through the vent line.  The length should have no effect on that.

I've been asked to prove it mathematically, but I can't seem to find anything that works or makes sense to me.  Most of what I come across is talking about liquids through a pipe competing with air pressure.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Because air is so low in viscosity and so light, the effect will be small. A shorter vent line will **decrease** the pressure a little because the shorter vent line will present less resistance to flow of the outgoing air.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the [Hagen–Poiseuille equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation) for laminar flow of a Newtonian incompressible fluid through a pipe:

$$\Delta P=\frac{8\mu LQ}{\pi R^4}$$

$\Delta P$ is the pressure drop, $L$ the length of the pipe and $Q$ the volumetric throughput. Rearranged we get:

$$Q=\frac{\pi R^4}{8\mu L}\Delta P$$

Although this model is only an approximation (air is not strictly incompressible, for instance, nor will flow necessarily be laminar) we can expect, all other factors remaining the same, that decreasing $L$ will increase $Q$.

Because air is so low in viscosity $\mu$, the effect will likely be small.

---

It's interesting to note that the case of *turbulent* flow basically leads to the same conclusion. In that case, for an incompressible fluid we can apply the [Darcy Weisbach equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%E2%80%93Weisbach_equation#Rough-pipe_regime):

$$\Delta P=f_D\frac{8Q^2}{\pi^2 g D^5}L$$

Where $f_D$ is a friction coefficient that depends on the Reynolds Number (a measure of turbulence) and the pipe's smoothness. Rearranged we get:

$$Q=\sqrt{\frac{\pi^2g D^5}{8f_DL}}$$

Here too, we can expect, all other factors remaining the same, that decreasing $L$ will increase $Q$. Due to the square root, the dependence of $Q$ on $L$ will be more pronounced in the turbulent flow case.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I used this to argue moving forward.  I had to change the memo though.  While the math worked, the tube is bent and hangs down.  Shortening the line causes it to bend flat at the top.  It doesn't arc as much as the longer one.  There was concern the line might kink so we're moving forward with an experiment to test the change in a production-like environment to be sure its safe for use.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad the answer served a purpose.